# Android: cannot run the application from sdcard

Tags: java, android, installation, apk

Okay, let get started!

### Problem

I`ve stuck with a problem with launching .apk files from sd card.
(testing with images have passed successfully, something goes wrong with executing .apk file)

## Solutions

I used these types of paths:

1. "/mnt/sdcard/fb.apk"
2. "/storage/emulated/0/fb.apk"
3. Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "fb.apk"

---

Related Code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File("/mnt/sdcard/fb.apk")), 
                                   "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

startActivity(intent); // Going wrong, I mean crashing.
```

---

#### What to change to make it work?

Comment: Hello! Welcome to StackOverflow, is there any stacktrace related to your error?

Comment: yeah, thanks for your reply. [link](https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/how-to-share-access-to-file-with-fileprovider-on-android-nougat/en) 
My error connected with this kind of problems: _android.os.FileUriExposedException: file:///mnt/sdcard/FavoriteBet/run.apk exposed beyond app through Intent.getData()_

And I am still looking the answer, how to launch .apk file from sd card

Comment: Still, nothing works.

Comment: ###The problem was Solved!###